# how to synchronise Between class controller contains AsyncTask and fragment

Tags: android

I am very very  tired 
I can't change visibility or an object in the fragment from the class controller 
 exmple  addIteamsAutomatic.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); return nullpointer

FragmentAddIteamsAutomatic :

public class FragmentAddIteamsAutomatic extends Fragment {

```
private EditText ssid, paswd;
public TextView afichage;
public Button parainage;
public Button validation;
public ProgressBar progressBar ;
public LinearLayout linearLayoutParm;
public static String sSSID,pWD;
private ControllerAddIteam controleAdd=null;


public FragmentAddIteamsAutomatic()

{

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_iteams_automatic, container, false);

    controleAdd.getInstance(getActivity());

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    ssid = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ssid);
    paswd = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.password);
    parainage = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnParainage);
    validation = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnValid);
    afichage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.affichage);
    linearLayoutParm = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayParam);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    afichage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    validation.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    parainage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sSSID = ssid.getText().toString();
            pWD = paswd.getText().toString();
            if (sSSID.equals(""))
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Vous Dever Remplir Tous les champs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                parainer();
        }
    });

    validation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            controleAdd.addSwitchToBase();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            ControllerAddIteam.accesDistant.send("getIteams", new JSONArray());
            // finish();
        }
    });
```

return  view;
    }

```
private void parainer(){

    controleAdd.getInstanceExecuteHandle();
}



}
```

---

ControllerAddIteam  :

public class ControllerAddIteam {

```
private static ControllerAddIteam instanceAdd = null;
private static Context context;
private static WifiUtils wifiUtils;
public static String SSID = null;
public static AccesDistant accesDistant;
public static Handler mHandler;



public static final ControllerAddIteam getInstance(Context context) {
    if (context != null)
        ControllerAddIteam.context = context;
    if (ControllerAddIteam.instanceAdd == null) {
        ControllerAddIteam.instanceAdd = new ControllerAddIteam();
        accesDistant = new AccesDistant();
    }
    return ControllerAddIteam.instanceAdd;
}

public static void getInstanceExecuteHandle() {
    new ParainageHandle().execute();


}

static class ParainageHandle extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    FragmentAddIteamsAutomatic addIteamsAutomatic=new FragmentAddIteamsAutomatic();



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        addIteamsAutomatic.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        addIteamsAutomatic.afichage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        addIteamsAutomatic.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(s.equals("valid"))
        {
            addIteamsAutomatic.linearLayoutParm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            addIteamsAutomatic.validation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            addIteamsAutomatic.parainage.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
        else  if(s.equals("notvalid"))
        {
            addIteamsAutomatic.parainage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

        addIteamsAutomatic.afichage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        addIteamsAutomatic.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



            if (values[0].equals("actwifi")) {
            if (values[1].equals("true"))
                addIteamsAutomatic.afichage.setText("WIFI DEJA ACTIVEE");
            else
                addIteamsAutomatic.afichage.setText("ACTIVATION WIFI EN COURS...");

        } else if (values[0].equals("scan"))

                addIteamsAutomatic.afichage.setText("START SCAN FOR Iteams STiTo ... Please Wait");

        else if (values[0].equals("find"))
                addIteamsAutomatic.afichage.setText("STiTo : "+getTypeFromSsid(SSID)+"  DETECTEE : "+SSID);

        else if (values[0].equals("connect"))
           addIteamsAutomatic.afichage.setText("CONNECTION WITH " + SSID + "En cours ...");

        else if (values[0].equals("connectOk"))
           addIteamsAutomatic.afichage.setText("CONNECTION WITH " + SSID + "ETABLISHED");
        else if (values[0].equals("connectKo"))
           addIteamsAutomatic.afichage.setText("PROBLEM OF CONNECTION WITH " + SSID);
        else if (values[0].equals("config")) {
           addIteamsAutomatic.afichage.setText("SENDING OF CONFIGURATION TO:  "+getTypeFromSsid(SSID)+"AND SAVING DATA");
            accesDistant.sendConfig(addIteamsAutomatic.sSSID,addIteamsAutomatic.pWD);
```

....

Comment: `FragmentAddIteamsAutomatic` is attached?

Comment: yes its a class

Answer (score 0):

1. You declare fragment in AsyncTask and doesn't call replace or add, it mean this fragment never show and it not call onCreateView

```
FragmentAddIteamsAutomatic addIteamsAutomatic=new FragmentAddIteamsAutomatic();
```

2. Maybe you should pass reference addIteamsAutomatic to class ControllerAddIteam. but please make sure it will be call on MainThread, because AsyncTask has method doInBackground in background Thread. best practice is wrap fragment reference by WeakReference

Comment: haw wrap fragment reference by WeakReference?

Comment: public class AddIteamActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager pager;
    TabLayout tab;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_iteam);

        pager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        tab = findViewById(R.id.tab);

        AddIteamsAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new AddIteamsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        pager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tab.setupWithViewPager(pager);


    }

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AddIteamActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager pager;
    TabLayout tab;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_iteam);

        pager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        tab = findViewById(R.id.tab);

        AddIteamsAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new AddIteamsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        pager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tab.setupWithViewPager(pager);


    }

}
```

Comment: Tell me what you need communicate? Between Adapter and activity?